# Can't find Microsoft Sync Framework Power Pack for SQL Azure nowhere

Tags: azure-sql-database, microsoft-sync-framework, data-synchronization

Hello,

I have a question regarding the above Power Pack. I can't seem to find none of the CTP's on the internet anymore, why is that? I really need the Sql Azure Data Sync for one of my projects, but i can't seem to find it. The link every one is pointing to is this one http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=bce4ad61-
5b76-4101-8311-e928e7250b9a&displaylang=en. but it redirects me to http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/default.aspx

Do you know where i can download the Power Pack at the moment. I've read some forums which said that the official release for Sql Azure Data Sync Service will be by the end of this year. But what happend to the CTP's?

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Power Pack features has evolved separately and has since been taken out of download sites.

The Sql Azure Sync Provider found its way to the SqlSyncProvider in Sync Framework 2.1. The previous utility that get's executed by Sql Agent has evolved to the Sql Azure Data Sync (currently in CTP).

If you want to do the sync by code, see the following:

[SQL Server to SQL Azure Synchronization using Sync Framework 2.1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sync/archive/2010/08/31/sql-server-to-sql-azure-synchronization-using-sync-framework-2-1.aspx)

[Windows Azure Sync Service Sample Available for Download](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sync/archive/2010/10/07/windows-azure-sync-service-demo-available-for-download.aspx)

If you want to find out about the Sql Azure Data Sync Service, check this out : [SQL Azure Data Sync Overview](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/sql-azure-data-sync-overview.aspx)

UPDATE: The SQL Azure Data Sync Service Preview is now available to anyone with an Azure subscription. Check out [SQL Azure Data Sync Preview is now available](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sync/archive/2011/10/13/sql-azure-data-sync-preview-is-now-available.aspx)

Comment: The problem is that i can not Sign up for the SQL Azure Data Sync Service (CTP) because when i navigate to this page  [link](http:connect.microsoft.com/sqlazurectps) it shows me the following message "Thank you for your interest in SQL Azure Previews.  The SQL Azure Reporting and SQL Azure Data Sync Service CTPs have concluded.   New previews will be launching soon!"

Comment: Doing the sync by coding it manually seems a little bit hard. I thought i could do it  with a helping wizard like when using a local database cache sync file, where you can select your database for sync and it generates the code for your on both the server and client sync file. My application will use a sync service where the sync methods will be.

Comment: Why would you want to use a CTP? it's CTP, not guaranteed and not supported. The sync service sample is almost complete you just need to change the scope definitions to reflect the tables you want to sync.